# Limited font size and execCommand

Tags: internet-explorer, wysiwyg, font-size

I want to change font size of selected text.  In Firefox everything is ok, but in Internet Explorer I can change font size only to some limited size, bigger numbers are not working.

```
sel_font = ...some number...

Editor.execCommand("FontSize", false, sel_font);
```

Does Internet Explorer have some restrictions on font size?  Can I use execCommand to change font size beyond this limit?

Comment: found a bug, on safari, but it looks like the same bug on internet explorer: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12874

Answer (score 2):

It's limited to 1-7 because of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536991(VS.85).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Here is best solution reference for master developer related to execCommand

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html#t010